Torsion in terms of parallel transport
This MO answer establishes the connection between parallel transport and torsion in the special case of the canonical flat connections on a Lie group. This suggests a more general construction for an arbitrary linear connection $\nabla$ on a manifold $M$. Let $\mathrm{tra}_\gamma^\nabla(t):T_{\gamma(0)}M\to T_{\gamma(t)}M$ be the parallel transport operator on $TM$ along a path $\gamma$. Letting $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ be a loop, we can construct another path $\tilde\gamma$ in $T_{\gamma(0)}$ given by
$$\tilde\gamma(t)=\int_0^t \left(\mathrm{tra}_\gamma^\nabla(s)\right)^{-1}\dot\gamma(s)\mathrm{d}s.$$
There is a formula in local coordinates that expresses the limit of this expression as we shrink the loop $\gamma$ by some infinitesimal factor $\epsilon\to 0$ in a local chart:
$$\tilde\gamma(1)^\mu=-\frac14 \epsilon^2 (\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\lambda}-\Gamma^\mu_{\lambda\nu})\int_0^1(\dot\gamma^\nu \gamma^\lambda-\dot\gamma^\lambda\gamma^\nu)\mathrm{d}s+O(\epsilon^3).$$
Question: is there a coordinate-free formula relating $\tilde\gamma(1)$ to the torsion tensor? I'm struggling to find any references.
